# How can we use the CDN URL mechanism for package management if we use Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

I need to use a package that can be resolved by CDN URL pointing mechanism, see [Material Icon package installation here](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/), like the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

However, when I wanted to use Icons from the above package like the following in my Typescript,

```
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
```

It tells me the following error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
```

I understand that I can solve the package missing problem by `npm install` the corresponding package (suggested like this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10571), but I am wondering if the CDN based package management can work for Typescript or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this to load icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Then you can only use icons like this:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

// To use an icon simply wrap the icon name (font ligature) with the Icon component:
<Icon>star</Icon>
```

Read these instructions: https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#font-icons

This doesn't really have anything to do with Typescript.

---

If you want to import individual icons (`import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';`), then you do indeed need to:

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```